# Close a "No Name" buffer opened with :e

Tags: buffers

How do I close a "No Name" which was opened with `:e ..` (explorer mode)? I tried `Ctrl-^` and `:bd!`, but the buffer is still there.

Comment: How exactly are you opening this "No Name" buffer? When using `:e ..` I get a NetrwTreeListing buffer, and I can open files from there... How exactly are you getting to this buffer? Did you try `:ls` to list the buffers? And while editing a different buffer on the current window, did you try something like `:bd #` or `:bd` followed by the number of the "No Name" buffer? Also, same question but `:bw` instead?

Comment: I still have not find a way to close all these explore buffer. :bd and :bw do not close it. just hide in background. when :ls i still see all those explorer buffers listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `:buffers` command to list your buffers, and then using `:bd` or `:bw` with the specific buffer number you want to remove?

```
:buffers
  5  a   "~/"                           line 1
 11  a   "H:\_unix_stuff_\Unix_Unleashed\UNIX.htm" line 1
 15  h   "[No Name]"                    line 1
:bd 15
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: ah!! I just realized your method works!! I have being trying :bd for so many times, they never work. the way i did it was to open the buffer using :b# . then from within the explorer mode buffer, i do :bd . with this method it just hide the explorer windows. i can still see the windows when i do :ls. Now i tried :bd# without opening the explorer buffer.. and indeed it closed the buffer !! WORK! Thank you Dan Pratt. So sorry i just paid very much attention into your method..  i never paid attention, because i have tried it inside the explorer window but never work.